# error in node.js TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createserver' at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aashish/chatbox/main.js:5:16)

Tags: node.js

i am facing some error in developing chat server client on linux please help

```
var http = require('http');
fs =require('fs');

var app = http.createserver(function (request, response)

     {
       enter code herefs.readfile("client.html",utf-8,function(error,data)
    {
        response.writehead(200,{'content-type': 'text/html'});
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
})
 }).listen(1337);

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket)

{
socket.on('message_to_server',function(data)


{
    io.socket.emit("message_to_client",{message: data["message"]});

});
    });
```

//    at Object. (/home/aashish/chatbox/main.js:5:16)

error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `createServer` where `S` is an uppercase letter

Answer (score 0):

`createServer()` is now deprecated meanwhile you could use `Server()` instead .. just check the following snippet or simply use [express](http://expressjs.com/) web framework.

```
var http  = require("http");

var server = http.Server(function(request, response) {
    response.end("heeloo world");
});


server.listen(3030, function(err){
    if(!err)
        console.log("success");
    else
        console.log("error");   
});
```